# Pass order success url redirect url to a payment gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, order-success-page

I would like to pass to an order payment a variable containing  the success url that a customer should get redirected to when the payment goes fine on the payment gateway page.
So basically I have a variable that I need to pass them.

Is there a way to achive this in magento 1.9?

this simple redirect does not work: https://myurl.com/checkout/onepage/success/